# Relativistic mass of electron in a potential

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, mass, electrons

An electron is accelerated through a 6 MV potential difference. what is the mass of the electron at the end of the path?

Comment: A: $m_i=m_f=0.510\;998\;910(13)\ \mathrm{MeV}$

Comment: Thank you, but can you please put down the steps ?

Comment: @Sarath step 1: look it up on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_rest_mass)

Comment: This is right in classical dynamics, not in relativistic mechanics . i am trying to derive the relativistic mass using mass dilation equation

Comment: Whether the concept of relativistic mass is useful is [debated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_in_special_relativity#Relativistic_mass). But you can find there how to calculate it, if you want.

Comment: Hi Sarah and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: Sarath, there is a very good argument that [the proper meaning of 'mass' in relativity is the invariant mas](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/133376/why-is-there-a-controversy-on-whether-mass-increases-with-speed)s and that the archaric usage 'relativistic mass' should be abandoned post haste. Of course, in answering question from a book one is stuck using the language of that book, but but you [shouldn't be asking for solutions to exercises for from textbooks](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/) on [physics.se] in any case.